# Write PDF metadata from the file name using Exiftool or PDFtk

Tags: command-line, pdf, pdftk

I have thousands of PDF files named in the format

```
Author Year Title of the book
```

The first two spaces are relevant: they make a break between the Author, the year and the title. The title could contain a number of space. I am looking for a script to write the **author** to the *author* meta field in the PDF; the Title to the title, and the year to the year metadata.  Exiftool seems the most promising of all the tools I looked at.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some EXIF manipulation tools have a built-in way to rename files based on EXIF data, but I don't know of one that can do it the other way round. So let the shell call the program with the right parts of the file names. Here's a script that processes just one file (pass the name as the sole argument of the script).

```
#!/bin/sh
title=${1##*/}
author=${title%% *}; title=${title#* }
year=${title%% *}; title=${title#* }
exiftool -Author="$author" -Title="$title" -CreateDate="$year" "$1"
```

Explanation: I use [parameter expansion constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to perform some basic string processing: put the base name (after the last `/`) into `title`; put the part up to the first space into `author` and remove that from `title`; repeat with the year.

To process all the files in a directory, put that code in a loop.

```
#!/bin/sh
for filename in *\ *\ *.pdf; do
  title=${filename##*/}
  author=${title%% *}; title=${title#* }
  year=${title%% *}; title=${title#* }
  exiftool -Author="$author" -Title="$title" -CreateDate="$year" "$filename"
done
```

To process all the files in a directory and its subdirectories recursively, use `find`.

```
find /path/to/top/directory -name '* * *.pdf' -type f -exec sh -c '
  for filename do
    …
  done
' _ {} +
```

Comment: Thank you Gilles. but, I am sorry I am not able to run it properly. I have no idea how these programs work. So, what I want is to put the script in Hazel (a mac application which automatically runs in the background. It can run Shell Scripts. It seems to require $1 as a means to feed the files to the scripts). I have tried replacing **$filename** by **$1**, with no luck. Yes, all of my files are stored in a folder. The reason I want to run it in Hazel is because the application can run the script in the future as I add more files to the folder.

Comment: @user3015087 I've turned the first snippet into a full script.

Comment: Yes, it is working now: almost there. The only issue is the **Year** is included into the **Title** field.

Comment: @Dellu That was a copy-paste error, I fixed it.

Comment: Hello, I am back after a while. This script is serving me well. So grateful!. But, I just noticed that the **Title** includes the file extension. is it possible to exclude the file extension?

Comment: @Dellu Add `title=${title%.*}`